# Understanding skip on server vs client in Meteor

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I just want to check because I don't see it in the docs. Maybe I'm just missing it.

As far as I can tell if I subscribe with skip then I don't skip on the client. Correct?

I'm using iron router. I have code like this

```
Router.route('/docs/:_page', {
  template: 'doclist',
  subscriptions: function() {
    var page = parseInt(this.params._page) - 1;
    var skip = page * 10;
    var limit = 10;
    return Meteor.subscribe("pages", skip, limit);
  },
});
```

The corresponding publish is this

```
Meteor.publish("pages", function (skip, limit) {
  return Docs.find({}, {skip: skip, limit: limit});
});
```

But now in the template helper I don't use the skip AFAICT because there's only `limit` results in the MiniMongo

```
  Template.doclist.helpers({
    docs: function () {
      var route = Router.current();
      var pageId = parseInt(route.params._page) || 1;
      var page = pageId - 1;
      var skip = page * 10;
      return Docs.find({}, {
         // skip: skip   
         limit: limit,
      });
    },
  });
```

It seems to work. If I comment in the `skip` line then I get no results on page 2.

Is that correct or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: That's correct. The publication sends a copy of the published data to the client, which is then stored in minimongo. The queries that are executed on the client side are only done against the data stored in minimongo. Since you're only publishing 10 documents at a time minimongo will only have 10 documents to pull, so no skip is needed on the client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct - the client does not require a `skip` in this case. Let's say you have 100 documents in the DB and you skip the first 20 with a limit of 10. Then only 10 documents will exist on the client. Whenever you `find` on the client (in your templates), you are querying the local database (in this case 10 documents), so a skip would be inappropriate.

I'll caution that all of this is predicated on the notion that you have **only one** subscription for `Docs`. To extend the example above, if you had another 15 documents in the same collection on the client from another subscription, then you may need to do some additional filtering in order to show only the ones you are are interested in.

Comment: Well so that has me curious, what are "best" practices for pagination? It seems like I could do `find({}, {skip: skip - limit, limit: limit * 3})` on the server and then `find({}, [skip: limit})` on the client so that switching one forward or back is already available? Or am I approaching this wrong? Should I just publish everything and meteor does the right thing? In that does the server only send what I `find` on the client or does it just start sending the entire DB? Sorry this seems like noob meteor questions. Also when are the results stable? I see them pop in currently.